# SEO friendly urls for mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I want to replace url `posts/:id` with `posts/:title` in mongo. Is there any way to do it. I tried using `key` in model

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title
  key :title
end
```

but my url does not change and also I am getting this error `Document not found for class Post with id(s)`

Am I missing sth here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Mongoid instead of the ActiveRecord you can use a gem called slugoid, 
[slugoid](https://github.com/jsy/slugoid)

to  generate pretty urls.

Comment: [Mongoid::Slug](https://github.com/papercavalier/mongoid-slug) is also a really good option, with a few more features.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using

> field :key

The correct syntax should be rather `key :field_name` 
For further reference on how to use the key check out 
[this link and scroll to the bottom](http://mongoid.org/docs/extras.html)

I doubt it would change the routes though.

Comment: sorry i edited the question.. but still its not working... as you said the routes did not changed

Comment: If you want to change the routes then you can specify the parameters like this `resources :users, :key => :username` in your routes.

Comment: I think this answer should be chosen